# serve React build locally

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, http

I am currently learning React, to eventually pair with Ruby on Rails.

I am following the tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7ejDZ8SWv8
to get a handle on the language.

I have **successfully compiled** the ***build folder***, running the command `$ npm run build`

I have also run the command `$ sudo npm i -g serve` in my terminal to install the **npm serve**

when running the build on localhost:8000, using the command `$ serve - s -p 8000` in the terminal, it is serving using `WEBrick::HTTPServer`, throwing the following up in the terminal:

```
[2022-09-12 15:03:22] INFO  WEBrick 1.7.0
[2022-09-12 15:03:22] INFO  ruby 3.0.0 (2020-12-25) [x86_64-darwin19]
[2022-09-12 15:03:22] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=5412 port=8000
```

which results in `localhost:8000` showing:

[image: localhost:8000]

My question:
Is there a way of altering this so I can serve my **react build** successfully, without causing issues when I go back to serving my RoR applications later?

Answer (score 0):

You are serving the whole project directory and since it can't find an index.html the browser displays that navigation of your folder structure.

```
serve -s build
```

Specifying you want to serve the build folder should fix it